# How to set environment variable in phpcloud?

Tags: php, web-hosting

Is it possible (and how) to set environment variable (like APPLICATION_ENV) in phpcloud hosting service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess file add following directive:

```bsh
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

Comment: As I have written in my comment to previous answer: Change of .htaccess would not be a solution, because same .htaccess file will be used in production environment.

Comment: This is how problem was finally **solved**: add .htaccess file not in project path (ie. /.apps/http/__default__/0/1.0-zdc), but one level above (ie. /.apps/http/__default__/0/). This way added .htaccess file will not be a part of project (nor in version control) but it will set environment variable which will be considered by apache.

Answer (score 1):

You can change php.ini settings using your .htaccess file.

Comment: can you add any examples or explain more? Welcome to stack exchange! ^_^

Comment: Hi, on phpcloud projects are deployed using git (`git push`, to be exact). I need to set environment variable on server which will determine application environment for configuration of Zend PHP project. Change of .htaccess would not be a solution, because same .htaccess file will be used in production environment.